# My battery stops charging randomly and then loses power

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, battery

I have a Lenovo E540 running Windows 10 x64. For quite a while now, I've been having problems with how the battery charges.

When I plug it in, it will always start charging - maybe for only 30 seconds, but it will start charging. After `x` minutes (totally random) it will stop charging and say `Plugged In, Battery Not Charging` and the battery will start to drain from then on. As it is plugged in, I don't get any warnings as to the battery level, so quite often my laptop suddenly sleeps because of it.

I've downloaded and installed all the latest drivers from Lenovo.

I've tried various power adapters at various locations.

There is some kind of pattern in when it stops, it generally is between:

- 25% and 35%
- 45% and 50%
- 65% and 75%

When it reaches these percentages, it will stop charging. By pulling the cable out then connecting it again, it will start charging again. If it's between those percentages, then often it will charge for only a couple of minutes. Once it stops charging, it will never charge again until disconnected and reconnected.

The one thing I have found is that if I turn the laptop off, then connect the power, it will charge to 100% no problems.

What can I do to fix this?

If any additional info is needed, please let me know in the comments.

Edits: I used to use it with Windows 8 and 8.1 (both x64) without any problems

Comment: Does it work any better if you do the same thing in the BIOS setup? That would point more clearly to either a hardware issue, or a software (Windows, drivers, utility software) issue.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Do you mean if I just open the BIOS and see if it does the same thing? I'm not sure if there is a battery indicator in the BIOS

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. There might not be a battery level readout, but if the computer does the same thing there, it will shut down at some point. (That should be perfectly safe as long as you don't change any settings.) You can then check the battery level when you turn the computer back on.

Comment: I have a couple of Lenovo laptops, and their Energy Manager software has quite a few few controls that you might find useful, including setting a charging plan, enabling and disabling conservation mode, and gauge reset.

Comment: @AFH what Windows version are your laptops running?

Comment: IMHO your battery is gone.

Comment: Friend had similar issue with similar Lenovo after **updating** to Win10. Short story: clean install (from pendrive) fixed everything. Longer story: update process breaks Lenovo power management soft. Maybe reinstall of said soft could fix it, but update process broke few other things so we went for "format c:". Note: you can easily test hardware with [Ubuntu on a stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: They came with Win 8 and 8.1, both updated to W10, and running different revisions of the software.